# How to remove Ytick marks but keep Ytick labels?

Tags: matlab, plot

My overall goal is to change the size of ONLY the x axis ticks.  But from my search it seems that that is rather difficult.

So, I tried to change the size of `'TickLength'`, and then remove the Y-axis ticks.  However, I still need the Y-axis labels.  Any suggestions as to how to accomplish either my overall goal, or the second approach?  Thanks.

Plotting code:

```
set(gca, ...
  'Box'         , 'off'     , ...
  'TickLength'  , [.19 .19] , ...
  'XMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YGrid'       , 'off'      , ...
  'Xgrid'       , 'off', ...
  'XColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'YColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'YTickLabel', int8([ylimits(1):ylimits(2)/3:ylimits(2)]), ...
  'YTick'       ,  []);
```

Comment: what Matlab version are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203282/setting-different-tick-lengths

Comment: Have a look at my update, the solution is quite simple nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Update

The R2014b update of the graphics engine introduced the following much simpler solution:

```
h = gca;
h.Box = 'off';
h.XRuler.TickLength = 50;
h.YRuler.TickLength = 0;
```

[image]

---

### Old answer

The only way I can think of, is to duplicate your `axes`, make the top one transparent (`'color','none'`) and then assign either x- or y- axis to one of the axes-objects and edit them independently:

```
f = figure(1)

plot(0:10,0:10);

ax1 = gca;
ax2 = copyobj(ax1,f)
set(ax1, ...
  'Box'         , 'off'     , ...
  'TickLength'  , [.19 .19] , ...
  'XMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YGrid'       , 'off'      , ...
  'Xgrid'       , 'off', ...
  'XColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'YColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'YTick'       ,  []);
set(ax2, ...
  'color'       , 'none', ...
  'Box'         , 'off'     , ...
  'TickLength'  , [.00 .00] , ...
  'XMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YMinorTick'  , 'off'      , ...
  'YGrid'       , 'off'      , ...
  'Xgrid'       , 'off', ...
  'XColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'YColor'      , [.3 .3 .3], ...
  'XTick'       ,  []);
```

[image]

If you get troubles while further editing your plot, e.g. things are not displayed properly because of the two axes objects, you can link your axes:

```
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property of the `YTick` as `[]` like the following example:

```
figure; 
plot(1:100, 1:100);

ax = gca; 
ax.YTick = [];
ylabel('y label');
```

This code give you this result:
[image]