# How to change font weight and size of some of xticklables matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to change the font weight and size of some of the xticklables. For example xtick 3,7, and 8. So far I found how to do it one by one. is there a way to do them at once?  here is an example to change xtick 3 font weight.

```
plot(1:10, rand(1,10))
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabel{3} = ['\bf' ax.XTickLabel{3}];
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169871/putting-certain-tick-labels-in-boldface-but-not-all-of-them/33720477#33720477),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `cellfun` function to generate the cell array of label strings and use the matlab array indexing to change some of the the elements of the `XTickLabel` property:

```
plot(1:10, rand(1,10))
ax= gca;
i= [3 7 8]; % the indices of the tick labels to change
ax.XTickLabel(i)= cellfun(@(s)['\bf ' num2str(s)],ax.XTickLabel(i),'UniformOutput',false);
```

Comment: Thank you! I also used it to change the font size `ax.XTickLabel(i)= cellfun(@(s)['\fontsize{20} ' num2str(s)],ax.XTickLabel(i),'UniformOutput',false);`